# I have to find all the voltages and current in the circuit

Tags: voltage, passive-networks, homework

[image]
I am given **Uab=100V**

**XL=6Ω**

**XC=3Ω**

**R=4Ω**

This is how I started

X=XL+XC=9Ω

**Ztotal**=sqrt(R^2+X^2)=9.84Ω

**Zab**=R+jXL=4+j6=7.21∠56.30

**I**=Uab/Zab=100/7.21=13.86A

but obviously I made a mistake somewhere

**U**=I*Ztotal=13.86*9.84=136.3V

**Uc**=I*Xc=13.86*3=41.58V

**UL**=I*XL=83.16V

**UR**=I*R=55.44v

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> X=XL+XC=9Ω

This isn't correct.

It's a bit confusing how reactance is defined, but inductive reactance and capacitive reactance have opposite signs when you combine them to determine the overall impedance, so you should have

$$ X=X_L - X_C $$

and you'll need to remember this is inductive reactance, so that you can combine it with the resistance to get the total impedance

$$ Z = R + jX$$

Where if the reactance was capacitive we'd use

$$ Z = R- jX_C.$$

Because of this confusion, I normally don't even work with reactance on its own, I just keep track of impedance

$$Z_L = j\omega L$$

and

$$ Z_C = \frac{1}{j\omega C}$$

When you combine impedances in series or parallel, you don't have to keep track of "off the books" signs.

> Ztotal=sqrt(R^2+X^2)

This isn't the total impedance (\$Z_{total}\$), it's the magnitude of the total impedance, \$\left|Z_{total}\right|\$.

Comment: okay so X=3 thus Ztotal=5, but can I turn R and XL into Zab? to get the current I, its the only thing that should be the same in series circuit, and for ZL and ZC I would need ω which I dont have

Comment: @make2r, \$Z_L = jX_L\$. \$Z_C = -jX_C\$, so you are given those values in the problem statement, without having to know \$\omega\$.

Answer (score 0):

Well, the input impedance is equal to:

$$\underline{\text{Z}}_{\space\text{in}}=-3\text{j}+4+6\text{j}=4+3\text{j}\tag1$$

Assuming that \$\text{U}_\text{ab}\$ is an effective voltage, we know that:

$$\hat{\text{V}}_{\space\text{R}+\text{L}}=100\sqrt{2}\tag2$$

So, the amplitude of the current trough that branch is given by:

$$\hat{\text{I}}_{\space\text{in}}=\hat{\text{I}}_{\space\text{R}+\text{L}}=\left|\frac{100\sqrt{2}\exp\left(\phi\text{j}\right)}{4+6\text{j}}\right|=\frac{100\sqrt{2}}{\sqrt{4^2+6^2}}=50\sqrt{\frac{2}{13}}\tag3$$

And so the amplitude of the input voltage is given by:

$$\hat{\text{V}}_{\space\text{in}}=\left|\underline{\text{Z}}_{\space\text{in}}\right|\cdot\hat{\text{I}}_{\space\text{in}}=\sqrt{4^2+3^2}\cdot50\sqrt{\frac{2}{13}}=250\sqrt{\frac{2}{13}}\tag4$$